# Gettiing cors error while implementing payment gateway on flutterflow

Tags: cors, stripe-payments, razorpay, flutterflow

I have been using flutterflow for development and i have come across a very common issue of cors while processing the payment. The payment integration used is within flutterflow (stripe) and using a firebase authentication. I have both the test and production keys. while testing the code i get the below error on inspect :

`Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-orovianew.cloudfunctions.net/initStripePayment' from origin 'https://orovia.flutterflow.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Tried changing the server on firebase but no resolution, reached out to the technical team but no response yet.